How to Style a Tooltip DIV to Match the Desired Design?
I am trying to style a tooltip <div> to match the design in this image: 
However, my current implementation looks like this:

Here is my current code:


.tooltip-container {
  @apply absolute top-[41%] left-[calc(50%+580px)] transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 z-10;
  @apply p-[16px] w-[220px] border-[1px] border-primary-blue-200 rounded-lg;
}

.tooltip-content {
  @apply flex flex-col items-center gap-3;
}

.tooltip-button {
  @apply text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-primary-blue ml-auto;
}

.tooltip-text {
  @apply text-[14px] font-normal leading-[20px] text-primary-blue-500;
}
<div className="tooltip-container">
  <div className="tooltip-content">
    <span className="tooltip-text">Click on a module to edit the learning objectives</span>
    <button onClick={onClose} className="tooltip-button">
          Got it
        </button>
  </div>
</div>




Maybe this is not the cleanest way to do it, but it gives the same result, using a ::before, like this:


.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #f9faff;
    border: 1px solid #cdd4e2;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: #2e3b8d;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    max-width: 300px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        margin-left: 30px;
    }

    .tooltip::before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            left: -10px;
            top: 50%;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-2px) rotate(45deg);
            background-color: #f9faff;
            border-top: transparent 1px solid;
            border-left: #cdd4e2 1px solid;
            border-right: transparent 1px solid;
            border-bottom: #cdd4e2 1px solid;
                        border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    }

    .got-it {
            display: block;
            margin-top: 10px;
            color: #2e73ff;
            font-weight: bold;
            cursor: pointer;
    }
<div class="tooltip">
    Click on a module to edit the learning objectives
    <span class="got-it">Got it</span>
</div>



